# .NET C# getting access violation when playing video with WMP

Tags: c#, .net, access-violation, wmp

I am making a program on Visual Studio using C#. This program plays a video when the user presses a button. I use the Windows Media Player library to play the video and all worked fine, until I tried it on a laptop with dual graphics adapters. These are **Intel HD Graphics 4600** and **R9 M256X**. On the laptop, any attempt to play the video leads to the program crashing immediately, with Visual Studio reporting an access violation (error 0xC0000005) in the console. I tried putting the code that plays the video in a try-catch block, but nothing was not caught.

Through testing, I noticed that the crash happens if in Radeon settings under the tab "Switchable graphics" I set my program to either Not assigned (default) or High performance but all works well if I set it to Power saving.

Ideally, I need a way to stop this from happening altogether, but a way to test if it is going to crash beforehand will suffice.

Some things of note:

- I tried creating a blank solution with just a video player and it still crashed, so the rest of the program isn't the issue.
- I tried playing two different videos and it still failed.
- It happens in both Debug and Release configurations.
- The program also has an unhandled exceptions handler but it can't catch the error either.

Comment: This is highly characteristic of a poorly-written video driver. Check to see if there is an update available for your drivers.

Comment: Do you use an P/Invoke code? Call native functions?

Comment: The fact that it works in power-saver mode is because in that mode the GPU isn't really working, it defers to the motherboards built-in GPU. This is a common feature in most modern laptops to save battery.
The fact that you cannot catch the error means it is happening outside the scope of the .net runtime, probably in a native rendering thread. You can dig deeper by trying to analyze the violation. Try using ProcMon to maybe catch the violation. The windows event log is also useful for driver errors.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon

Comment: I am seeing a similar issue - but I have an nvidia Geforce 940MX.  Using the nvidia control panel it "fixes" the problem if I explicitly set my app's exe to use Integrated Graphics.

Comment: Did you fine a solution to this? I'm having this same problem.